# Change the URL of a video file

Tags: video, video-streaming

This may look like a silly question.... :-)

I have a video file on my server,

This is the url of it...

http://www.mydomain.com/videos/intro.flv

Now I need get a url something like this

http://www.mydomain.com/watch?v=w_y1_iownG4/

I mean, I need to get a streaming URL. Like YouTube.

Does that make any sense to you ?

Does anybody know how to do that ?

Your help will be appreciated...

Thanks..

Comment: Well, looks like nobody knows... :-(